# How to unauthenticate Google App Engine plugin?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I installed the GAE plugin to my Eclipse and I authenticated. Now I would need to change the user but there doesn't seem to be any way to log the user out.

Any advice? Reinstall the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you sign out by clicking the button at the bottom of Eclipse?

[image: Google Plugin Sign Out button]